# Translate a word only in a WordPress product page with a specific product category

Tags: wordpress, product, categories, translate

I am currently on a global translation:

```
function change_translate_text( $translated_text ) {
    if ( 'Nederlands'  === $translated_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Engels';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_translate_text', 20 );
```

I want this code to only to trigger when people visit the PRODUCT PAGE of a certain Product Category/Slug/ID on WordPress.

Can someone help a front-end designer? :D

Kind regards, :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work nicely if it's just one category you need to check against (just change CatIdHere to the cat id)

```
function change_translate_text( $translated_text ) {

     global $product;
     $id = $product->get_id();

     if( has_term( CatIdHere, 'product_cat', $id ) ) {

          if ( 'Nederlands'  === $translated_text ) {
               $translated_text = 'Engels';
          }
          
          return $translated_text;
     }

}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_translate_text', 20 );
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this is giving me a 500 HTML error code. 
Copy-pasted it exactly and only replaced CatIdHere with the right ID: 1027

if( has_term( 1027, 'product_cat', $id ) )